# Limit the amount of results returned by a filter query in Solr

Tags: solr

I'm working on a project which uses Solr as its search engine. Is it possible to limit the amount of results returned by a filter query in Solr?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

yes, of course ... you can specify parameters `rows=xxx` in your query

details - [CommonQueryParameters](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/common-query-parameters.html#CommonQueryParameters-TherowsParameter)

Comment: The above link is broken, Please refer this link [Solr Query Param # rows](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/common-query-parameters.html#CommonQueryParameters-TherowsParameter)